# ANTLRv4: How can I check efficiently whether a sentence satisfies a given grammar?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

This question is basic enough. If I have a sentence and a grammar how can I check efficiently whether this sentence is part of the grammar. By efficient way I mean a way which uses minimum amount of computations/resources. Here's what I did. I implemented a class `ErrorListener` which extends the already defined `BaseErrorListener`. This class `ErrorListener` has a single field `boolean error` which tells us whether a parse error was encountered during the parsing phase. At the start `error` is set to `false` and is updated to `true` when `public void syntaxError(...)` is called. Also before the parser's start state is invoked the statements

```
ErrorListener listener = new ErrorListener();
parser.removeErrorListeners();
parser.addErrorListener(listener);
```

are called. So after running some tests I stated to think that this approach might not the optimal one especially if this is formed as an query. So I was wondering is there another way of doing all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal resources would be consumed by starting with the following:

```
parser.removeErrorListeners();
parser.setErrorStrategy(new BailErrorStrategy());
try {
    parser.ruleName();
    System.out.println("The sentence was contained in the grammar.");
} catch (ParseCancellationException) {
    System.out.println("The sentence was not contained in the grammar.");
}
```

And then updating this to also use the two-stage parsing strategy descibed in the ANTLR 4 book.